# Notice: Undefined offset error in array with switch

Tags: php, arrays, switch-statement

This is my PHP CODE for Menu with selection.
Its working with errors, please help me.

**CODE**

```
<?php
                            $page_url = array();
                            $page_url[0]= "/bookslibrary.net/index.php";
                            $page_url[1]= "/bookslibrary.net/about.php";
                            $page_url[2]= "#";
                            $page_url[3]= "/bookslibrary.net/become-member.php";
                            $page_url[4]= "#";
                            $page_url[5]= "/bookslibrary.net/contact.php";

                            $page_urlActive = array();
                            $css_active = "class='active'";

                            switch ($_SERVER['PHP_SELF'])
                            {
                                case $page_url[0]: $page_urlActive[0] = $css_active; break;
                                case $page_url[1]: $page_urlActive[1] = $css_active; break;
                                case $page_url[2]: $page_urlActive[2] = $css_active; break;
                                case $page_url[3]: $page_urlActive[3] = $css_active; break;
                                case $page_url[4]: $page_urlActive[4] = $css_active; break;
                                case $page_url[5]: $page_urlActive[5] = $css_active; break;
                            } echo ("
                                <li $page_urlActive[0] ><a href='".$page_url[0]."'>Home</a></li>
                                <li $page_urlActive[1] ><a href='".$page_url[1]."'>About</a></li>
                                <li $page_urlActive[2] ><a href='".$page_url[2]."'>Books of the Month</a></li>
                                <li $page_urlActive[3] ><a href='".$page_url[3]."'>Become a Member</a></li>
                                <li $page_urlActive[4] ><a href='".$page_url[4]."'>Ahlus-Sunnah</a>
                                    <ul>
                                        <li><a href='#'>Web Directory</a></li>
                                        <li><a href='#'>Add Your Website</a></li>
                                    </ul>
                                </li>
                                <li $page_urlActive[5] ><a href='".$page_url[5]."'>Contact</a></li>
                            ");
                        ?>
```

**ERROR**

Notice: Undefined offset: 1 in (...FILE_PATH...)header.php on line 34

Comment: There is no line 34. When posting code and a line reference, do something to highlight the line. Like a code comment.

Comment: line 34 is:
<li $page_urlActive[1] ><a href='".$page_url[1]."'>About</a></li>

Comment: Did you check if `$page_urlActive[1]` is _in fact_ set?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

your `$page_urlActive` contains only one item, with a key depending on page you are on. And you are trying to echo elements for all indexes, you can get rid of this notice by initializng array with all indexes:

```
$page_urlActive = array_fill(0, 6, '');
```

Comment: ISSUE HAS BEEN RESOLVED WITH YOUR ADVICE.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is the specific index (0-5) of `$page_urlActive` may not be set depending on the active page.

A better approach would be to refactoring your code to loop over the `$page_url` array. Inside the loop test if the current `$page_url` equals the requested page. If so, output the appropriate `class` attribute. This would remove a lot of unnecessary code (e.g. `switch`, `$page_urlActive`).

While I advocate clean code, at the end of the day, this is just a *Notice* and not a hard *Error*.